# Is it possible for dynamic branding of the application

Tags: ios, branding

I have the application that will connect to different servers. Each server is like different client and I want my app to look different (as far as I can) depending on which server it is connected to. I thought that I can have a ZIP that on handshake will be returned from destination server and use details from it e.g. Images, settings etc.

Is it possible, if so what is the limit?

**Edit**
I'm thinking about the images for logo etc. and some color lists that I can then use with fallback to defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make all resources (images, string files, NIBs, storyboard...) be downloaded from the client server.

Also, there are several project developed exactly for dynamic design using CSS-like mechanisms:

- http://www.pixate.com
- http://www.freestyle.org
- https://github.com/robertwijas/UISS
- https://github.com/tombenner/nui

There are some project to run Javascript as well. This may allow you customise some business logic.

- http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-example/
- https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/JavaScriptBridge

So, yes. It's possible, but you'll find some limitation, like the root view controller, the app delegate, etc.. You'll have to be creative.

I've never done something similar, so I can help any further then this.

Comment: I think this is most usable answer for me, others were informative also but with less examples.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for almost all elements of the application except:

1. Application name
2. Application icons
3. Application splash
   screens

Those 3 items are bundled into application and can't be changed in runtime.
Rest of the items have so called appearance selectors that can be used to implement dynamic branding.

Comment: Is it as simple as unpacking to destination then loading a file and using it in e.g. Navigation Controller bar?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Yes, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible, as I have worked on an App like this myself. We did it basically the same way you described. On startup the user selects a server to connect to and we download a zip file that contains all the assets for that client. After the download, the UI is loaded with the custom images. You can customize any UI element the system lets you, which is pretty much everything, except for minor details like the system StatusBar. You're gonna need some helper classes that make your life easier and support methods like, for example, `[UIButton themedButtonWithImage:]`.

Comment: Can you share the code for this method? If possible:) I would like to see what exactly it helps with:)

Comment: No, sorry, it's proprietary code. But I'd guess we're not the only people who have done this, google a bit for iOS UI theming related stuff, maybe there's some open source code you can use for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's *possible* — in one extreme, you could have an app which consists entirely of a UIWebView (plus some mechanism for selecting which server the app is talking to) that gets almost all it's content from the server.

There are performance considerations if you do (internet connection reliability, cost, and speed), and Apple may object to certain things being done on any app distributed through the app store, but assuming you follow their guidelines or distribute outside the store, the only limits that I know of are the app icon, the startup screen, and the app identifier, which have to be included in the bundle.

Comment: The web view based app is not an option.